# C++ CInternetSession connexion lost

Tags: c++, timeout

I use `CInternetSession` to get and post request. But when a `connexion` time out occurs, I lost the `connexion` and I always get invalid server request error, I don't understand why. Moreover, there is also a memory leak.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "httpConnexion.h"
#include "TSException.h"

ChttpConnexion::ChttpConnexion()
    : CInternetSession(AfxGetAppName(), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE)
    , m_lastRequest()
{       
    SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
    SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, 10000);
    m_bAttente = true;
}

ChttpConnexion::~ChttpConnexion()
{
}

std::string ChttpConnexion::sendRequest(const std::string& strUrl)
{   
    DWORD dwServiceType;
    CString strServerName;
    CString strObject;
    INTERNET_PORT nPort;
    AfxParseURL(strUrl.c_str(), dwServiceType, strServerName, strObject, nPort);

    CString strHeaders = _T("User-Agent: User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    CString strTmp = "", strResult = "";
    CHttpConnection* pHttpConnexion = NULL;
    CHttpFile* pHttpFile = NULL;

    try
    {   
        //Creation de la connexion Http
        pHttpConnexion = GetHttpConnection(strServerName, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, nPort, NULL, NULL);

        //Creation de la requete GET
        pHttpFile = pHttpConnexion->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, strObject, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE);

        //Envoi de la requéte
        BOOL bRequestSend = pHttpFile->SendRequest(strHeaders);

        CString headers;headers.Empty();
        DWORD dwRet;
        pHttpFile->QueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,headers);
        pHttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);

        //Lecture du résultat
        while ( pHttpFile->ReadString(strTmp))
        {
            strResult += strTmp;
        }

        //Fermeture de la requéte
        pHttpFile->Close();

        //Fermeture de la connexion
        pHttpConnexion->Close();

        //Suppression des objets
        if (pHttpFile != NULL)  
            delete pHttpFile;

        if (pHttpConnexion != NULL) 
            delete pHttpConnexion;
    }
    catch(CInternetException* exp)
    {
        exp->Delete();

        //Fermeture de la requéte
        if (pHttpFile != NULL)
        {
            pHttpFile->Close();
            delete pHttpFile;
        }

        //Fermeture de la connexion
        if (pHttpConnexion != NULL) 
        {
            pHttpConnexion->Close();
            delete pHttpConnexion;
        }
        throw CTSException("sendRequest");
    }       
    return strResult.GetString();
}


std::string ChttpConnexion::postRequest(const std::string& strUrl, const std::string& postData)
{    
    DWORD dwServiceType;
    CString strServerName;
    CString strObject;
    INTERNET_PORT nPort;
    AfxParseURL(strUrl.c_str(), dwServiceType, strServerName, strObject, nPort);

    CString strHeaders = _T("User-Agent: User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    CString strTmp = "", strResult = "";
    CHttpConnection* pHttpConnexion = NULL;
    CHttpFile* pHttpFile = NULL;

    try
    {   
        //Creation de la connexion Http
        pHttpConnexion = GetHttpConnection(strServerName, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, nPort, NULL, NULL);

        //Creation de la requete GET
        pHttpFile = pHttpConnexion->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, strObject, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE);

        //Envoi de la requéte

        BOOL bRequestSend = pHttpFile->SendRequest(strHeaders, (LPVOID) (LPCTSTR) postData.c_str(), postData.length());

        CString headers;headers.Empty();
        DWORD dwRet;
        pHttpFile->QueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,headers);
        pHttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);

        CString data;
        GetCookie(strServerName, "sess_id", data);

        //Lecture du résultat
        while ( pHttpFile->ReadString(strTmp))
        {
            strResult += strTmp;
        }


        //Fermeture de la requéte
        pHttpFile->Close();

        //Fermeture de la connexion
        pHttpConnexion->Close();

        //Suppression des objets
        if (pHttpFile != NULL)  
            delete pHttpFile;

        if (pHttpConnexion != NULL) 
            delete pHttpConnexion;
    }
    catch(CInternetException* exp)
    {
        exp->Delete();

        //Fermeture de la requéte
        if (pHttpFile != NULL)
        {
            pHttpFile->Close();
            delete pHttpFile;
        }

        //Fermeture de la connexion
        if (pHttpConnexion != NULL) 
        {
            pHttpConnexion->Close();
            delete pHttpConnexion;
        }
        throw CTSException("postRequest");
    }   

    return strResult.GetString();
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: As it seems SO tried to tell you, there is a lot of code here, please cut it back to where errors are occurring.

Comment: I don't know where error occurs... I get a request timeout , and it jump in the catch statement. After that no wait to reconnec properly

Comment: @Nagasaki I don't see a question, but it looks like you're asking us to debug your program for you; and you've been a member long enough to know how the community will react if you do that without showing your previous effort

Comment: My question is why when a connexion timeout occurs, when i send a new request i get a server response error. I can't tell more, if i know the response, i won't ask for it...
i don't need debugging, my code works well until time out occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when you construct your object and you call `CInternetSession` constructor, why the 3rd param is NULL? It should be something like `PRE_CONFIG_INTERNET_ACCESS`. You may need to use the proxy settings if you are behind a proxy.
- check the content of `strServerName`, it may be invalid and `GetHttpConnection` fails because of that.
- in your `try`, you `GetHttpConnection` and `OpenRequest`, but you don't check if the results aren't NULL. You only check later (too late) if they aren't NULL to delete them. You should check them after `GetHttpConnection` and `OpenRequest`, before using them. (But I guess the exception occurs during `GetHttpConnection`)
- if the timeout occurs after 10sec, maybe it's because your timeout is too low (in your constructor).
- there were some old reports that https may be a problem. But you didn't mentioned what was your request and what you were requesting.
- in your request header, you are requesting different file formats (xml, html, png, etc...), but you are using a GetString and appending it to a string. If you are getting a binary data, it may not work. You should use a char[] buffer. [Check this example.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1876/Retrieving-a-file-via-HTTP)
- after using your object `ChttpConnexion`, did you call `.Close()` on it?

In the end, I would recommend attaching a debugger and put a breakpoint in the catch to see where exactly the error occurs, or add some debug logs. This may help.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I will modify my code in that way.
I already modify the timeout to 60s.
The url I request is https protocole.
I only request for html file.
After using object `ChttpConnexion`, I just delete it.

Comment: I didn't get awarded the 300 bounty, any ideas why?